# Как сделать проверку на тип данных в PHP?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку на тип данных в аргументах в функции в PHP? Т.е. вот есть функция

```
function calc($a, $b) { echo $a + $b; }
calc(а, б);
```

и как сделать вводимые буквы недопустимым типом данных, чтобы не было результата вообще, или ошибка была?

Знаю, что легко, но совершенный новичок в PHP :) буду благодарен за объяснение!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант.

1. ) Указать то, что функция будет принимать и отдавать (string / int)
   Пример:

```php
function calc (int $a, int $b): int
{
    return $a + b;
}
```

То есть, функция принимает два параметра и оба типа Int (числовое), то, что после двоеточия - это то, что функция возвращает

2. ) Если функция может принимать смешанные данные (mixed), то можно сделать небольшую проверку.
   Пример:

```php
function calc($a, $b)
{
   if(gettype($a) !== 'integer') {
        $result = 'Переменная $a не является числом';
   } elseif(gettypes($b) !== 'integer') {
        $result = 'Переменная $b не является числом';
   }
   else {
        $result = $a + $b;
   }
return $result;
}
```

3. ) Можно просто привести перевести переменные в любой тип данных:

```php
function calc ($a, $b) {
    return (int) $a + (int) $b;
}
```

Тогда при вызове calc(5, 5) мы получим 10, но если одно из значений не будет цифрой, то оно будет равно нулю, то есть calc(5, 'стркоа') = (5 + 0) = 5.